# install mdadm without user input in wheezy

Tags: bash, mdadm, debian-wheezy

I am switching to debian from ubuntu and setting up RAID0 on my AWS boxes using user-data. Things were working fine on ubuntu but on wheezy

`apt-get -y install mdadm --no-install-recommends`

throws a user input box

> If the system's root file system is located on an MD array (RAID), it
>   needs to be started   early during the boot sequence.  If it is
>   located on a logical volume (LVM), which is on MD, all constituent
>   arrays need to be started.  If you know exactly which arrays are
>   needed to bring up the root file system, and you want to postpone
>   starting all other arrays to a later point in the boot sequence, enter
>   the arrays to start here.   Alternatively, enter 'all' to simply start
>   all available arrays.  If you do not need or want to start any arrays
>   for the root file system, leave the answer blank (or enter 'none').
>   This may be the case if you are using kernel autostart or do not need
>   any arrays to boot.  Please enter 'all', 'none', or a space-separated
>   list of devices such as 'md0 md1' or 'md/1 md/d0' (the leading '/dev/'
>   can be omitted).

I want to select `all` automatically. I have tried `echo -e 'all' | apt-get -y install mdadm --no-install-recommends` and also [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338857/automatically-enter-input-in-command-line) but no success till now, can any one please help me out here.

Comment: Is that what you tried verbatim, or did you actually do `echo all | apt-get -y install mdadm --no-install-recommends`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working with [debconf-set-selections](http://man.he.net/man1/debconf-set-selections)

This is what I did before installing mdadm

```
- echo "mdadm mdadm/mail_to string  root" | debconf-set-selections
- echo "mdadm mdadm/initrdstart string  all" | debconf-set-selections
- echo "mdadm mdadm/autostart boolean true" | debconf-set-selections
- echo "mdadm mdadm/autocheck boolean true" | debconf-set-selections
- echo "mdadm mdadm/initrdstart_notinconf boolean false" | debconf-set-selections
- echo "mdadm mdadm/start_daemon  boolean true" | debconf-set-selections
- apt-get -y install mdadm --no-install-recommends
```

I hope this helps some one.

Update: Above stated method works fine, I found a simpler way to do this:

`export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -q -y install mdadm --no-install-recommends`